# Update a Docker Image on an EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running the Docker Engine. I created an ECS Repository, which I can successfully push new images to and pull that updated image to other machines.  However when I do a `docker run`  and try and pull latest from the repository, I don't actually get the latest, I just get the first version I pushed. I'm guessing there's some kind of versioning to prevent you from pushing a bad version to production without being able to revert.

I'm aware that there is a concept in ECS called Tasks, but the AWS Documentation isn't stellar so I don't have a great understanding of what it is.  Is there some task I need to set up to properly version these images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with aws. The problem is using the `latest` tag.

When you run a container with latest tag `docker run some_image:latest`, docker engine searches it's local repository for `some_image` with `latest` tag. If it's finds it in local repository, docker-engine doesn't bother searching remote repository. So you always end up running the very first version of your docker_image.

So, to prevent ambiguity,  the best practice is **not** to run docker image with `latest` tag.